# Stick Header and Footer on page reloading in laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, performance, laravel-blade

My Laravel website take too much time on loading views I am using master blade system and have same header and footer on my all pages so i want to make them stick and load only the child part to load . I have no idea how to do that I am new learner . IF any one know how to do that please share it.

Comment: You should use SPA to do this.

Comment: You might need javascript frameworks or libraries to  do that.

Comment: Optimizing queries and code will help in speed up page loads. Also check whether the views are cached or not.

Comment: How I optimize queries and code can you describe in detail?